# Adding custom labels to FrameTicks. How to do that?

Tags: plotting, ticks

Here is my code:

> xticks = {{1 -> "Country"}, {2 -> "Classic"}, {3 -> "Pop"}, {4 ->
>   "Rock"}}; ListPlot[{101.861, 101.971, 97.796, 98.541}, Joined -> True,
>   PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, {97, 103}}, FrameLabel -> {"Music Genre",
>   "PSNR"}, GridLines -> Automatic, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None},
>   {xticks, None}}, Frame -> True]

I am trying to have the labels: Country, Classic, Pop and Rock at x-axis values of 1,2,3 and 4. However, it seems I am doing something wrong. What is the right code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You only need to place comma instead of the arrow in the ticks. Try this:

```
xticks = {{1, Rotate["Country", 70 Degree]}, {2, 
   Rotate["Classic", 70 Degree]}, {3, Rotate["Pop", 70 Degree]}, {4, 
   Rotate["Rock", 70 Degree]}}; 

ListPlot[{101.861, 101.971, 97.796, 
  98.541}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, {97, 103}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Music Genre", "PSNR"}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {xticks, None}}, Frame -> True]
```

Returning this:

[image]

Have fun!